# How to exclude GIC distributor initialization during Linux kernel booting

Tags: linux-kernel, multiprocessing, arm, embedded-linux, interrupt

I am new to Linux kernel, and now working with an AMP system on a 4-core Cortex-A53, where 2 cores are for RTOS and the other 2 for Linux.

The issue is RTOS and Linux share some H/W resource, like GIC controller and SMMU(IOMMU). I would like to initialize them(write to their register) by RTOS before booting the Linux kernel. Linux will only use these shared resource, but skip the initialization(e.g. irqchip_init()) during kernel booting.

Is it possible? Can I make it by kernel build configuration? If possible, how should I describe them in device tree?

I know this is a rare implementation case. Does anyone have experience?

Comment: Would  removing two CPUs from your Device Tree, and performing whatever GIC/IOMMU initialization/RTOS-related CPUs  wakeup  is needed as SMC services in your Arm Trusted Firmware fullfill your requirements ?

Comment: We use up to EL1 in both OS. Does it sound difficult?

Comment: The GIC supports trustzone.  You need to put your RTOS in the secure world and Linux in the normal world.  There are some settings like FIQ mode that need to be set in the secure world, so you need an `smc` for linux to set this.  The last time I used Linux 3.xx time frame, this was in the Linux GIC drivers.

Comment: Google does not understand the 'GIC and banking' as an appropriate search term.  [GIC and Trustzone](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100336/0002/aba1462965062700).  The global GIC registers need to be banked so that each world can operate on them without influencing the others.  If you take the tact you have, you will have to modify both stacks.  You can have secure code on the Linux cores to handle the features that fit the partitioning you need.